# React/Flux/React-Router: How to call to store data when re-routing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reactjs-flux

Tools: React 0.14.0, Vanilla Flux and React-Router

I'm having an issue when it comes to re-routing outside of the IndexRoute. **-I'm not sure how to call for store data for the next Component.**

For Example: A Simple Routing

```
<Route path="/" component={Main}>
    <IndexRoute component={Component1} />
    <Route path="newPath" component={Component2} />
</Route>
```

Component1(The IndexRoute) and Component2 use the same data from the store and initialize the same

```
function getInitialState() {
    return {
      object1: null,
      object2: null,
      object3: null
   }
}
```

And they are updated the same way:

```
function getStateFromStores() {
    return {
      object1: Store1.get(),
      object2: Store2.get(),
      object3: Store3.get(),
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

**But the IndexRoute is sure to call getStateFromStores() because it will listen for the initial loading into the store but Component2 will still be null when routed to.**

My Not-So-Sure-Solution

If I set up the stores to return "null" when they are empty I can make Component2 render with its data by setting changing it's initialization like so:

```
function getInitialState() {
    return {
        object1: Store1.get(),
        object2: Store2.get(),
        object3: Store3.get()
    }
}
```

I'm worried that my solution might be more of a hack then a solution and that there is probably a common Component Life-cycle and/or React-Router technique to load components

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing that in `componentWillMount` instead of your component constructor. That lifecycle event will give you time to pre-populate your local state before your component mounts on the DOM.

Comment: I'd also take a look at redux https://github.com/rackt/redux and it's React bindings: https://github.com/rackt/react-redux Makes this all a lot simpler via the connect decorator.

Comment: function componentWillMount() {
    return {
        object1: Store1.get(),
        object2: Store2.get(),
        object3: Store3.get()
    }
}     Like this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that comment, but you would do `componentWillMount() { this.setState( { object1: Store1.get(), object2: Store2.get(), object3: Store3.get() } ); }`

Comment: I'm excited to move over to Redux I'm probably going to hold off a little longer till I've used Flux a little more.

Comment: Redux only shares some tangental relations to vanilla Flux. Learning Flux isn't really that important, as Redux focuses more on functional programming concepts. Learning those and how Redux uses them doesn't really matter if you've learned the Flux concepts. I'd just skip to it and start using it now.

Comment: Wow...I was never told that...... dang it. I prolly spent waaaay too much time with flux then :/

Comment: No worries. I don't think you've wasted your time, as knowing Flux doesn't hurt. But you can move closer to the finish line by jumping to Redux now and it shouldn't be any more difficult for you to do so :)